# Deleting port on one openvswitch bridge causes change in MAC address on another bridge

Tags: networking, openstack, openvswitch

I am trying to set an explicit MAC address on an openvswitch bridge
named `br-ex`.  I am running Fedora 20 and using the native
`ifdown`/`ifup` commands to configure the bridge (details of my
network configuration files are at the bottom of this question).

After re-recreating `br-ex` by running `ifdown br-ex` followed by
`ifup eth0`, my OVS configuration looks like this:

```
# ovs-vsctl show
1ab8ae7e-e9da-4af9-9226-03b54f5d2544
    Bridge br-int
        Port br-int
            Interface br-int
                type: internal
        Port int-br-ex
            Interface int-br-ex
        Port "tapa1747c68-d3"
            tag: 1
            Interface "tapa1747c68-d3"
                type: internal
    Bridge br-ex
        Port "eth0"
            Interface "eth0"
        Port br-ex
            Interface br-ex
                type: internal
    ovs_version: "2.0.1"
```

Note the MAC address on `br-ex`:

```
# ip link show dev br-ex
80: br-ex: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether fa:16:3e:ef:91:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Now delete port `int-br-ex` from `br-int`, *which is no longer
connected in any way to `br-ex`*:

```
# ovs-vsctl --if-exists del-port br-int int-br-ex
```

And note that the MAC address on `br-ex` has changed:

```
# ip link show dev br-ex
80: br-ex: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether f2:2a:d3:bf:3c:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

What just happened?

### Network configuration

I have, in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`:

```
# cat ifcfg-br-ex
DEVICE=br-ex
DEVICETYPE=ovs
TYPE=OVSBridge
ONBOOT=yes
OVSBOOTPROTO=dhcp
OVSDHCPINTERFACES=eth0
MACADDR=fa:16:3e:ef:91:ec

# cat ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE="eth0"
ONBOOT="yes"
BOOTPROTO=none
TYPE=OVSPort
DEVICETYPE=ovs
OVS_BRIDGE=br-ex
```

What's going on here?  Why is the MAC address on `br-ex` changing?
How do I make it stick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is not possible to set a persistent MAC address on an OVS bridge using the `ip set link` command.  Instead, you need to set via `ovs-vsctl`:

```
ovs-vsctl set bridge br-ex other-config:hwaddr=$MACADDR
```

If you're on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora, you can accomplish this by setting the following in your interface configuration file:

```
OVS_EXTRA="set bridge br-ex other-config:hwaddr=$MACADDR"
```

Comment: In `/etc/network/interfaces` (Debian / Alpine Linux) I used: `post-up ovs-vsctl set bridge br0 other-config:hwaddr=00:00:00:aa:bb:cc`